# How to monitor multiple docker container on the same host using topbeat?

Tags: docker, monitoring

We are currently experimenting with Beats to monitor our docker containers. Currently we have a setup so that we need to install Beats in every Docker Container that we create. This gives overhead per container. Is there a way to use Beats (topbeat) in a way that we can install it on a host so it monitors all containers that are running on that host?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with beats/topbeat. According to the [topbeat](https://github.com/elastic/topbeat) page, that's now deprecated so you should use [beats](https://github.com/elastic/beats).  I guess it sort of depends what kind of stats you're trying to capture but if it's some basic cpu/mem/io stuff then a quick google found me [dockerbeat](https://github.com/Ingensi/dockerbeat) - which, according to the landing-page readme, can run as a single container on your host and will produce stats for each container on there. Looks like there's a [published image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ingensi/dockerbeat/) on dockerhub too. (I should say I've not used this, but it looks like it might fit the problem you're having?)